# image url path settings to display image from firebase storage on a website

Tags: reactjs, firebase

i have a website with reactjs as a front-end.i have uploaded an image on firebase storage from my website page .The image name is 1 (the id of tutor). Now want to get the same image on an other page.the code is as follows:

```
 ///
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {storage} from '../firebase';

export default function TutorDetails(props) {
 const[image,setImage]=useState(null);
  const[url,setUrl]=useState('');

//the name of image is 1 which is tutor.tutorId
  //
storage.ref(`images`).child(`${tutor.tutorId}`).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
    setUrl(url);
    
   console.log("url:",url);
   
    
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle any errors
  })
return(
    <img src={url||'https://via.placeholder.com/400x300'} alt="tutor photo" height="300" width="400"/>
)
}
```

the error is that file name becomes the part of path and error 404 is displayed .here is console error

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/smartcollegeimages.appspot.com/o/images%2F1
```

please note that the folder name is images and file name is 1
thanks in advance for help.